# is there a recommended number of p-values when using q-value estimation for FDR control?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, false-discovery-rate

I have created a Spearman correlation matrix for 6 variables (A1,..A6) to evaluate their relationships. I have thus obtained 15 *p*-values:

```
pvals = c(0.00316, 0.0038, 2.0e-15, 0.31, 0.58, 0.55, 0.37, 0.81, 0.93, 0.29, 0.0157, 0.007, 0.0049, 0.98, 0.041)
```

I am more worried in losing any of the positive correlations rather than having Type I errors. Therefore, instead of focusing of controlling FWER I would like to control the FDR. I can certainly use the qvalue package in R to obtain *q*-values for my list of *p*-values. Is it statistically correct or appropiate to use this application for such a short list of *p*-values? What would be the correct pi0 estimate method (smoother or bootstrap)?

Comment: How do you reach at 15  p values ? Should n't it be 21p values?

Comment: You are right sorry, I meant 6 variables not 7 so the number of p values is $\frac{N\times(N-1)}{2}$

Comment: please give expanded versions of abbreviations and what does q values mean and how do you compute these values ?